# Создание графических приложений в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте, вот начал работать с графическим интерфейсом в вижуал студии. 
Но сразу возникло много вопросов. Насколько я понял в 2012 версии убрали Windows Forms , но можно было самому сделать через CLR проект. Погуглив , нашел мануал по созданию и сделал. Вроде как все работает, но не понимаю что для чего нужно. 
Стандартных есть 2 файла . Заголовочный и соответственно с исходниками (.cpp) Привожу содержимое

**MyForm.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace VoidList {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    #include <stddef.h>
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

        protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
        protected:

        private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

        #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button ());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1 -> Location = System::Drawing::Point (106, 117);
            this->button1 -> Name = L "button1";
            this->button1 -> Size = System::Drawing::Size (71, 19);
            this->button1 -> TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1 -> Text = L "HelloWorld";
            this->button1 -> UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1 -> Click += gcnew System::EventHandler (this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls -> Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L "MyForm";
            this->Text = L "MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        #pragma endregion
        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            MessageBox::Show ("Hello world",
                "MessageBOX", MessageBoxButtons::OK,
                MessageBoxIcon::Question);
            Close();
        }
    };
}
```

**MyForm.cpp**

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <stddef.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    VoidList::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Вопросы :

2. Где нужно писать само тело программы. Когда создал действие по нажатию на кнопку, оно поместилось в заголовочный файл, там и надо описывать работу с компонентами ?
3. STAThread насколько я понял это точка входа в программу, откуда будет начинаться выполнение ? Если не так , поправьте пожалуйста .
4. Объясните пожалуйста как можно подробнее что такое ref класс, читал так и не понял.
5. Объясните пожалуйста синтаксис объявления меин функции void Main(array^args)
6. Как правильно подключать созданные ранее классы (в каком файле и т.д) .
   Спасибо за ответы заранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, .NET-приложения нужно писать на C#, у вас сразу отвалится куча вопросов (например, 3, 4 и 5 из вашего списка). C++/CLI — отвратительный монстр, питающийся мозгами разработчиков.

Затем, откажитесь от устаревших ещё в прошлом тысячелетии богомерзких WinForms, перейдите на каноничный WPF, и ваши волосы сразу станут мягкими и шелковистыми, надои возрастут и HP удвоится.

Теперь по пунктам.

1. Нету такого понятия «тело программы». Программа разбита на классы и методы. Каждый класс лучше писать в отдельном файле (то есть, двух файлах: `.h` и `.cpp`), но вы можете и сложить всё в кучу.
2. `STAThread` — это атрибут потока, в котором будет выполняться функция `Main`. Именно эта функция является точкой входа. Атрибут означает, что стартовый поток будет работать в single threaded COM-apartment (это нужно для объектов Winforms, которые «живут» в этом потоке.
3. `ref class` — это элемент C++/CLI, в нормальном C++ не существует. Это ключевое слово вводит .NET-овский класс, в отличие от нормального C++-класса (который вводится ключевым словом `class`).
4. Функция `Main` принимает .NET-ссылку (`^`) на .NET-массив (`array`) ссылок на .NET-строки (`String^`) и ничего не возвращает (`void`).
5. Если файлы в том же проекте — через `#include`, как обычно. Если файлы в другом проекте — через подключение зависимостей на уровне проекта (и директиву `using`).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ , просто нужно на С++ писать (такое задание). 
И где правильно писать действия по нажатию на кнопку ? в заголовочном файле ? просто по дефолту оно перекидывает в заголовочный , просто я думал что в заголовочных обычно пишутся прототипы , ну или гетеры и сетеры для для классов, либо мелкие функции тип inline

Comment: Да, не повезло вам с заданием. Надеюсь, это не учебное задание, и за него вам заплатят по двойному тарифу.

Я бы попробовал писать обработчики событий так же, как и все методы: декларация в заголовочном файле, сама функция в `.cpp`. (Если, конечно, так получится: C++/CLI полон неожиданностей.)

И ещё, открою вам секрет, вы пишете **не на C++**. Язык C++/CLI относится к C++ примерно так же, ка птица-секретарь к генеральному секретарю.

Если C++ необходим, возможно, вам стоит подумать о переходе на Qt.

Comment: Есть ведь визуальный редактор и для форм на `C++/CLI`, почему Вы им не пользуетесь? Куча вопросов бы отпала

Comment: Не выходит делать обработчик событий в другом файле , так как методы (события по нажатию и так далее ) объявлены как private

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov: То есть как это не выходит? В C++ всегда можно было, вне зависимости от того, что объявлено `private`, а что `public`. Вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov Я позволю себе встрять в диалог: вы, судя по всему, совсем недавно *открыли* для себя `Visual Studio` и `C++`. Не стоит занимать позицию "там в Майкрософте все неправильно сделали, чтобы ничего не получалось бы" и т.п. Забыв гордость, полезно (причем часто) потратить время, чтобы понять *философию* подхода, чтобы понять рациональность функциональности.